# Unable to log in to vtiger Extension Store

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I have an instance of vTiger 6.4 installed on Hosted server and am having problems with the extensions marketplace.

I have a created an account, but when I try to log in, **I get an error that says 'Unauthorised'.**

I tried to login with [Market Place](http://marketplace.vtiger.com/) and i am able to login.

I have checked that in config.inc.php file my Site is also correct with trailing slash.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to reset your password using **Forgot Password** from this [link](https://marketplace.vtiger.com/customer/Login) and then try to login in your CRM as well Market place site. Might be you have problem with your password.